# SQL Server 2014 all column properties disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm hardly trying to change my Identity Increment setting for a primary key column in my SQL Server 2014. Sadly all properties are greyed out and not changeable at all! 
Can someone tell me why and how to fix it?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column properties are always readonly. So don't click on "Properties" but "Modify".

[image]